# Load file from classpath using OPCPackage in OSGi environment

Tags: java, osgi, apache-poi, classloader, osgi-bundle

I'm trying to load a rather large .xslx file (29MB) to process in Java using POI.

Because of the uncompressed file size when reading the file in memory using an `InputStream`, I run into heap space issues.

As recommended on Stackoverflow, I make use of an `OPCPackage` to not have to load the entire file in memory.

I try to load the file using the `OPCPackage` open method. This method accepts:

- File
- <del>InputStream</del> (Cannot load file in inputstream - OutOfMemory)
- Path

### File option

Problem is that we are working in an OSGi environment, so when trying to create a File with the asset path. The asset path is in fact a link to the bundle

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/excel/file.xslx");
File file = new File(url.toURI()); // URI = bundle://449.124:/excel/file.xlsx
```

So following Exception occurs: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"`

Trying to use the URL path instead also is not successful:

```
File file = new File(url.getPath()); // Path= /excel/file.xslx
if(!file.exists()){
    // FILE DOES NOT EXIST
}
```

### Path option

When I try to use the path open method, it cannot seem to resolve the path, since I always get following Exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Zip File is closed`

```
opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(url.toURI().getPath()); // Path= /excel/file.xslx
```

Any ideas on how I can reference my file from within a bundle environment in order for it to load? Or am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot process the input stream, then you could copy the input stream to a File in the bundle data area and then process that file.

Resources in bundles do not stand alone on the file system, so you would need to "extract" them to a file if necessary.

Comment: Hi BJ, this is how I started implemented it after asking the question. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a few pieces from the Excel file, you could also use the [streaming API](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) of Apache POI, this way you do not need to store the file in temporary disk-space and you can process arbitrary large files.